# Markov chain steady state existence

Tags: statistics, markov-chains, markov-process, stationary-processes

Is it possible for a Markov chain to have no steady state solution ? What is an example of such system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *finite* Markov chain always has at least one steady-state distribution. If the transition matrix is $A$, each column of $A-I$ sums to $0$, so $A-I$ doesn't have full rank, and there is at least one nontrivial solution to $Ax=x$.

On the other hand a Markov chain with an infinite state space doesn't have to have a steady-state distribution. For example, consider the chain with state space $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$, where state $k$ transitions to state $k+1$ with probability $1$.

Comment: When does the finite case have more than 1 s-s distribution? and when is it unique?

Comment: @atulgangwar: I _think_ a necessary and sufficient condition for having a unique steady state is that the transition graph (with one edge for each nonzero transition probability) has exactly one terminal strongly connected component _and_ this component contains either a self-loop or two cycles of coprime length.

Answer (score 0):

In the excellent discussion of Markov chains in Feller's "Introduction to Probability Theory and Applications," the term "steady state" appears nowhere.  If your definition coincides whith "persistent state", then that means that the probability $f_{ii}$, given an initial state of $i$, of returning to $i$ eventually, is 1.  More precisely,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{(n)}(i) = 1
$$
where $f^{(n)}(i)$ is the probaility or a first return to state $i$ at time $n$.

The contrasting term to "persistent state" is transient state.  My own example of a Markov chain with no persistent state at all is as follows:

Consider a chain whose transition map is 
$$
M : [0,1) \mapsto [0,1) : M(x) = \{ x\sqrt{2}\} $$
where the notation $\{w\}$ means the fractional part of $w$, that is, $w-\lfloor w \rfloor$.

The states of $M$ are the reals on the half-open interval $[0,1)$.  No state will every repeat exactly, so there is no persistent ("steady") state.

Comment: Persistent states concern countable Markov chains. In this context, the example on [0,1), while intrinsically interesting, might be slightly misleading.